# Where is facebook pulling my canonical url from?

Tags: facebook, sharing, canonical-link

page in question:
https://play.decksi.com/share/45431f8d

faceook debugger link:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.decksi.com%2Fshare%2F45431f8d

For some reason, facebook is taking our app page ID as the canonical url, despite it not being on the page at all...

I have the exact same view on a sandboxed instance, and it behaves fine..

This worked fine until today (well i noticed today)...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) does already show why it picked up the apps.facebook.com page as the canonical URL, but in case you need to manually check:

It's in the HTML source of that page:

```
$curl 'https://play.decksi.com/share/45431f8d' 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="decksi_switchboard">
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="Decksi" />
<meta property="og:type" content="activity" />
```

---

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://apps.facebook.com/playdecksi" />
```

---

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://play.decksi.com/Content/img/decksi_logo_bg.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Decksi" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100002131000570" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah! so the answer is in fact, that we are geo-gatting this content (canada) and of course facebook is hitting from a US server!! So my curl doesn't look like yours, voila. – Monsters X 8 secs ago edit